# JBAS014516: Failed to acquire a permit within 5 MINUTES

Tags: java, jboss6.x

I encountered a Jboss error in my application. Pasting the stack trace below:

```
06:08:12,331 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/10.3.144.46:8180-23) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component ThirdPartyPaymentProcessorBean for method public abstract java.util.Map com.business.ws.thirdparty.ThirdPartyProcessorBeanLocal.processRequest(java.util.Map): javax.ejb.EJBException: JBAS014516: Failed to acquire a permit within 5 MINUTES
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.strictmax.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:109) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:272) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:368) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
... 36 lines omitted ...
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:559)
```

Why does this error occur? And what action should I take to fix it?

Comment: In order to balance the outages and down time, we have two Data centers to host the application. One of the data center is experiencing this issue and the other is fine. How do I find out the issue with the specific EJB Bean and it is exhausted to provide the expected results?

Comment: This error was disappeared after server restart. Server restart reloaded all the JARS and it removed all the EJB connections which are hanged. Can this be the solution to this error?